# Three knights or knaves, three different hair colors

Tags: logical-deduction, liars

In a group of three people (A, B and C), everyone has a different hair color (blond, black or brown, not necessarily in this order) and everyone may be either a knight (always telling the truth) or a knave (always lying).
This is what they say.

- Blond-haired person: "C has brown hair".
- Black-haired person: "C is a knave".
- Brown-haired person: "A and B are knights".

Determine the hair color of C.

Comment: A tiny little doubt - According to your question, is it that they all are knights or all are knaves.  or one knight and the others knaves and so on.

Comment: @Ak19 Each of them can be either a knight or a knave - they don't have to be all of the same kind.

Comment: @Ak19 - In fact, they cannot all be the same kind by the second question. If they're all knaves or all knights, the black-haired person could not say that "C is a knave".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One possibility is that

> The brown-haired person and black-haired person are A and B in some order. Then since they are both knights, the black-haired person speaks the truth when he says that C is a knave.

This means that

> C is the blond-haired man, who is clearly lying when he says that C has brown hair (because he's describing himself!) Therefore C has blond hair.

Comment: oops sniped... bye

Comment: coming back with explanations for other cases :) +1!

Comment: I'll accept your answer because you were the first to answer correctly, but how did you rule out all the other cases?

Answer (score 5):

> Blond

Explanation

> See the following images... they also explain the other cases
>  [image: enter image desc here]
>  [image]

Conclusion

> C is a knave with blond hair, A and B are knights with black/ brown hair

Answer (score 4):

El- Guest and OK have got the answer before me..

C is

> Blond haired

Explanation

> First let's start from the black haired person. If he were a knight, C would be a knave and can't have black hair. If he were a knave it would directly imply that C can't have black hair. (as he would be telling about himself in both cases)
> $$$$
> Next from the blond haired person. If he were a knight, then C would have brown hair. Now C can be a knight or a knave. If C were a knight, A and B both would be knights with any one of them with black hair. So, this would imply that C is a knave. But this is a contradiction.
> So if C were a brown-haired knave, A and B would be knaves with any one blond-haired. This would imply that blond haired person is a knave, again a contradiction.
> $$$$
> So, the blond haired person must be a knave and it must be **C** .